# IIS 7.5 FTP "error in the push function"

Tags: firewall, ftp, iis-7.5, ftpes

The Setup:
Server 2008 R2 Enterprise with IIS 7.5
Home connection with dynamic external IP

The Goal:
Encrypted passive ftp server with AD integration
no client side adjustments (save making sure to use ftpes in their client)

The Problem:
I'm running on a home connection with a dynamic external IP and the firewall is apparently doing something screwy

What Happens:
It works intermittently (its broken more often than not)
The control ports seem to work fine but not the data ports, because it can contact authenticate and its gets all the way to the point where its supposed to pull the Virtual directory

Dump of FileZilla console follows(identifying info is edited):

Status: Resolving address of xxxxx.dyndns.org

Status: Connecting to 123.123.123.123:21...

Status: Connection established, waiting for welcome message...

Response: 220 Microsoft FTP Service

Command: AUTH TLS

Response: 234 AUTH command ok. Expecting TLS Negotiation.

Status: Initializing TLS...

Status: Verifying certificate...

Command: USER topherhead

Status: TLS/SSL connection established.

Response: 331 Password required for topherhead.

Command: PASS ********

Response: 230-[[welcome message is usually here]] site 222222

Response:     Directory has 624,490,864,640 bytes of disk space available.

Response: 230 User logged in.

Command: SYST

Response: 215 Windows_NT

Command: FEAT

Response: 211-Extended features supported:

Response:  LANG EN*

Response:  UTF8

Response:  AUTH TLS;TLS-C;SSL;TLS-P;

Response:  PBSZ

Response:  PROT C;P;

Response:  CCC

Response:  HOST

Response:  SIZE

Response:  MDTM

Response:  REST STREAM

Response: 211 END

Command: OPTS UTF8 ON

Response: 200 OPTS UTF8 command successful - UTF8 encoding now ON.

Command: PBSZ 0

Response: 200 PBSZ command successful.

Command: PROT P

Response: 200 PROT command successful.

Status: Connected

Status: Retrieving directory listing...

Command: PWD

Response: 257 "/" is current directory.

Command: TYPE I

Response: 200 Type set to I.

Command: PASV

Response: 227 Entering Passive Mode (123,123,123,123,253,199).

Command: LIST

Response: 150 Opening BINARY mode data connection.

Error: GnuTLS error -53: Error in the push function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The chances are good that your firewall supports FTP by watching the control connection (basically what you pasted above) and opening ports dynamically to enable the data connection to be made (where it said: "150 Opening BINARY mode data connection.").

You've encrypted the control connection.  The firewall can't see inside to do that.

What you'll want to do is edit the firewall to permit a range of ports (how many depends on the number of clients you'll have) to enter (or leave, if you're permitting "active" PORT commands instead of or in addition to PASV).  You will then need to configure the FTP server to only use those ports.

It is hard / annoying, but I've seen it work with at least one secure FTP server

Comment: well that seems logical and all, but i recall actually setting a value in the firewall compatibility section of IIS, and it didnt work...  HOWEVER, i do also remember running a port scan and those selected ports not being open(its a really bad firewall) i did actually forward them to the server so methinks the firewall is the weak link here

Comment: well i ended up taking a lazier however still effective way out.
what i got from your answer was that the control channel was encrypted, so i thought about it and i ended up just changing SSL requirements to be just on credentials and the control channel itself is unencrypted but the data is its not quite as secure as it could be but i just cant picture someone creeping on control data...
anyways thanks for planting the idea in my head